# React Native: How can I import commun class from a single file

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native, react-native-ios

How can I import one single file and this file imports all my helper class?

For exemple, I load all those helpers class in all my «scenes» classes.

```
import Styles from "./Styles";
import I18n from "./I18n";
import Helper from "./Helper";
import Images from "./Images";
[...]
```

So if one day I want to add a new helper class, I need to open and add this new class in all my «scenes» classes. So how can I make something link this?

## /App/Scenes/Index.js

```
import * from "./Bootstrap"

Styles.foo
I18n.t("foo.bar")
```

## /App/Helpers/Bootstrap.js

```
import Style from "./Styles"
import I18n from "./I18n"
import Helper from "./Helper"
import Images from "./Images"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) them from your bootstrap.js

```
import Style from "./Styles"
import I18n from "./I18n"
import Helper from "./Helper"
import Images from "./Images"

export {Style, I18n, Helper, Images}
```

Then you can use it in the index.js

```
import * as Helper from "./Bootstrap"

Helper.I18n('something')
```

But honestly, I do not really get why you would actually need that. Just because you add a new helper does not mean you have to update all your files. It just means that you have to update the files that actually use the new helper. So you have to update these files anyway and your IDE will help you doing the import automatically.

Comment: I'm coding with Sublime Text and it doesn't import automatically class. Maybe there's a package for this, I'll check this!

Thanks :)